# how to show an image from memoryimagesource?

Tags: .net, image, show, memoryimagesource

```
        return toolkit.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(rawWidth, rawHeight, oneDPixMod, 0, rawWidth));
```

anyone knows how to show that image using panel or label maybe?
do i need to use class Graphic, like g.drawImage()?

thks for the answer

Comment: I assume this is a question about .Net?
Please make sure you provide enough info for everyone to comprehend your question.

Comment: What is this toolkit ? and what is MemoryImageSource ? this is not a .NET built-in class...

Comment: @AndreasT: please don't edit the tags unless you're sure about them. This is Java, not .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a form with a PictureBox, just set the PictureBox's Image property to the return value from toolkit.CreateImage():

```
pictureBox1.Image = toolkit.CreateImage(...);
```

Comment: Sorry, thought this was a .Net question. Based on the .Net tag that AndreasT incorrectly added. You should correct the tags and add "java" and "netbeans".